# Table not found when creating Stored Procedure to insert data

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-connection, psql

I am creating a stored procedure with the data set found from this [repo](https://github.com/devrimgunduz/pagila), after I imported the data using the pagila-insert-data.sql file.

The procedure is used to insert data into the `staff` table. Below is the command I am using to create the procedure:

```
psql -c 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE staff_insert_data("first_name" text, "last_name" text, "address_id" text, "email" text, "store_id" smallint, "active" text, "password" text, "picture" text) LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ INSERT INTO public.staff VALUES ("first_name", "last_name", "address_id", "email", "store_id", "active", "password", "picture"); $$;'
```

When I execute the command I get an error saying:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "public.staff" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...t, "picture" text) LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ INSERT INTO public.staff VALU...                                                           ^
> ```

I don't understand why it says the `staff` table does not exist. I can confirm the table exists. When I execute `\d "public.staff"` the output is:

```
                                          Table "public.staff"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 staff_id    | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('staff_staff_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name  | text                     |           | not null |
 last_name   | text                     |           | not null |
 address_id  | smallint                 |           | not null |
 email       | text                     |           |          |
 store_id    | smallint                 |           | not null |
 active      | boolean                  |           | not null | true
 username    | text                     |           | not null |
 password    | text                     |           |          |
 last_update | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 picture     | bytea                    |           |          |
```

To be clear I have tried multiple iterations of *public.staff* with and without double quotes, without the public schema, and with single quotes.

Comment: Advice: never ever use double quotes “, these are the first step in creating bugs. And who wants bugs? And if you think you need these quotes, fix your code to avoid the need for double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any quotes for the fully legal Postgres table name `public.staff`.

The only explanation that makes sense is that your `psql` call without any explicit connection parameters defaults to a different database (and cluster) than you expect. And (luckily!) there is no table of the same name.

Fix by providing one or more of (database_name, port, role) to psql explicitly. Like:

```
psql -d mydb -p 5432 -U myuser -c 'CREATE ...'
```

Detailed instructions in the manual chapter ["Connecting to a Database"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING) for psql.